# ASP.NET AJAX Accordian for each row

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I have an accordian layout and i want to show this on search result that are generated on SQL Server.

[image]
Which control i should pick for that . Repeater ? GridView? ListView? or DataList ? **I want pagination too**

It's code is

```
    <asp:Accordion ID="Accordion1" HeaderCssClass="accordionHeader"
    HeaderSelectedCssClass="accordionHeaderSelected"
    ContentCssClass="accordionContent" runat="server" SelectedIndex="0" FadeTransitions="true"
    SuppressHeaderPostbacks="true" TransitionDuration="250" FramesPerSecond="40"
    RequireOpenedPane="false" AutoSize="None" Width="898px">
    <panes>
<asp:AccordionPane ID="Accpane1" runat="server">
    <Header>
        <asp:Label ID="lblMemberId" runat="server" Text="VN10000001"></asp:Label>
    </Header>
    <Content>
        <div class="thumb">
            <a href="viewprofile.aspx">
                <asp:Image ID="imageProfilePic" ImageUrl="~/user/images/User.png"
                    class="img-responsive" runat="server" AlternateText="User Image" />
            </a>
        </div>
        <ul class="login_details1">
            <li>
                <asp:Label ID="lblLastLogin" runat="server" Text="Last Login"></asp:Label></li>
        </ul>
        <p class="description">
            <asp:Label ID="lblAge" runat="server" Text="Age"></asp:Label>&nbsp;
                                , &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="lblHeight" runat="server" Text="Height"></asp:Label>&nbsp; |
                                 &nbsp;<span class="m_1">Religion</span>&nbsp; : 
                                &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="lblReligion" runat="server" Text="Religion"></asp:Label>&nbsp; | 
                               &nbsp; <span class="m_1">Education</span> : 
                                &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="lblEducation" runat="server" Text="Education"></asp:Label>&nbsp; |
                                &nbsp; <span class="m_1">Occupation</span> : 
                                &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="lblOccupation" runat="server" Text="Occupation"></asp:Label>&nbsp;<br />
            <a href="viewprofile.aspx" class="read-more">View Full Profile</a>
        </p>
    </Content>
</asp:AccordionPane>
</panes>
</asp:Accordion>
```

Comment: repeater that runs with a custom control that have your layout

Comment: Sorry. i forgot to tell you that i want pagination too. Can repeater wil be able to do that job?

Comment: repeater can not automatic make paging, you need to make it manually...